# LoD for subtraction

Tags: tableau-api, business-intelligence

Hello I have a question about using LOD For subtraction in tableau.

I have a table with different dimensions such as customer name, sales group, distribution center and measures that I need to work with is subtracting products that was SHIPPED from FORECAST using LOD TO Compute this and get a percentage difference between the two measures using those dimensions.

Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a measure called Amount.  You can get the Total Amount by Customer Name:

```
{ FIXED [Customer Name] : SUM[Amount] }
```

And let's say you have another measure called ForecastAmount.  You can get that total by Customer Name:

```
{ FIXED [Customer Name] : SUM[ForecastAmount] }
```

So if you create two calculations using those formulas, you'll have the basis for your percentage difference.  The formula for percentage difference is:

```
ABS([LOD Amount] - [LOD ForecastAmount]) / (([LOD Amount] + [LOD ForecastAmount])/2)
```

(and then format that result as a percent, or multiply it by 100).

You can apply the same logic to your other dimensions.

Comment: Hello thanks for the response what I’m really trying to do is subtract the shipped from forecast , I don’t have any measure called amount , I need to subtract those measure at the Level of detail stated above

Comment: @sandraknowles : I gave a generic example because your question lacks detail.  So, replace Amount in my example with your shipped measure.